# Add text to php drawing

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, drawimage

**I have this code, and I want to add a text that shows above the arc (door of the house), but I am having difficulties in adding it. Can anyone help? I have added my code.**

`````
header("Content-type: image/png");
$img_width=800;
$img_height=800;
$img=imagecreatetruecolor($img_width, $img_height);
$white=imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0);
$black=imagecolorallocate($img,255,255,255);
$red=imagecolorallocate($img,255,0,0);
$yellow=imagecolorallocate($img,0,255,0);
$blue=imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,255);
$orange=imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 200, 0);
imagefill($img,10,10,$white);
imagerectangle($img,$img_width*2/10, $img_height*5/10,$img_width*4/10, $img_height*8/10,$red);
imagefill($img,10,15,$blue);
imagepolygon($img,[$img_width*3/10, $img_height*2/10, $img_width*2/10, $img_height*5/10, $img_width*4/10, $img_height*5/10], 3, $yellow);
imagefill($img, 10, 15, $yellow);
imagearc($img, $img_width*3/10, $img_height*8/10, 100, 200, 180, 360, $red);
 imagefill($img, 10, 15, $orange);
imagepng($img);
?>````
`````

Comment: Where is your code that you attempted to add the actual text itself? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156045/adding-text-to-images-with-php

Comment: "having difficulties "...please show the code you tried which is giving you difficulties. And then please explain specifically what goes wrong.